# Validate file extension on Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

I want to validate the file extension on Symfony3 before the file is uploaded. Until now, I am using this code (this is a simplified version just used as a snippet):

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $file = $form->get('file')->getData();
    $ext = $file->guessExtension();
    if($ext !== 'myextension' ){
        die('not allowed');
    }

    $name = md5($file->getClientOriginalName().time());
    $full_name = $name.'.'.$ext;
    $dir = __DIR__.'/../../../web/upload';
    $file->move($dir,$full_name);
}
```

Question is: will the file be uploaded in the temp directory anyway? is this safe? is there a better way to do it?. My biggest concern is that someone tries to upload a binary file or a script. Thanks

EDIT (thanks Gabriel Diez): the file is a property of an entity. I used assert to declare it:

```
   /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="20M")
     */
    private $file;
```

Comment: Is this File a property of an Entity ?

Comment: Right, I used it as an assert:
   /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="20M")
     */
    private $file;

Comment: File extension is only string in a name. Checking it does not save you from users uploading virtually any kind of file. If you want to be safe(er), put it somewhere, where it can not be executed by web server. It's a popular topic, there are quite a bit of questions on file upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the better way to do it is to secure it using Symfony. As this file is part of an Entity you can use the Assert/File annotation to add some constraints and security.

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "20M",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
 *     )
 */
private $file;
```

With this Symfony will handle this on the server side and return an error to the user if the type isn't allow. Moreover with this method you are sure users can upload only available types of file.

You can find a list of existing mime types [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) and a list of all constraints of symfony available  [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#mimetypes).

Comment: Note that if you upload a php file which generates a valid PDF, the upload will be ok cause his mime-type will be considerated as `application-pdf`.  
Combine @Assert and extension validation would be better.  
(I guess this comportement depends on the server configuration)